# Angular 5 http with basic auth doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, angular, http, basic-authentication

I am trying to make the a `http.get` request with a `basic` auth where I have a `token` as a username and then an `empty` password.

```
const  headers_object = new HttpHeaders();
headers_object.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
headers_object.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(environment.CVRTOKEN + ':'));

const httpOptions = {
    headers: headers_object
};
const url = 'https://rest.cvrapi.dk/v1/dk/suggestions/company/' + searchString;
return this.http.get(url, httpOptions);
```

However it doesn't seem to work. What have I done wrong?

When looking at the console I get the following error:

```
VM3464:1 GET https://rest.cvrapi.dk/v1/dk/suggestions/company/3 401 (Unauthorized)
```

And the request headers look like this:

[image]

Comment: can you share the console error you are getting

Comment: do you not have a password for this user?  usually you have to encode `user:pass` as base64 but I see you're just encoding `user:`

Comment: @jtate for this api the username is the token and the password should be empty

Comment: @MarcRasmussen is this request working in postman? try doing there as it might me authorization issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`HttpHeaders`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders) is an immutable type, which means that `append` returns a *new instance* of `HttpHeaders` rather than modifying the existing version. In your code example, you're not actually setting the `Content-Type` and `Authorization` headers. You can use the following to set the headers correctly:

```
const headers_object = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa(environment.CVRTOKEN + ':')
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code but it gives me errors. Try declaring the httpOptions like this to see if it works

```
httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(this.username + ':' + '')
   })
};
```